# c++: use or not use namespace in function argument list

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Consider such simple example:

```
namespace foo {
    struct Foo {};
    struct Boo {
        void f(Foo);
    };
}

using foo::Boo;

void Boo::f(Foo)
{

}
```

`clang` and `gcc` compile such code without errors (`-pedantic` `-std=c++11`),
but `VC++-2015` report error about  `Foo` type in `void Boo::f(Foo)` - `Foo` underclared identifier. If rewrite code like this: `void Boo::f(foo::Foo)` it compiles just fine, but what interesting it also compiles after such rewrite:

```
namespace foo {
    struct Foo {};
    struct Boo {
        void f(Foo);
    };
}

void foo::Boo::f(Foo)
{

}
```

is it `VC++2015` bug according to `c++11` standard?

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't an MSVC bug.  You should properly namespace your identifiers.

Comment: But why `vc++` accept last variant then without `properly namespace`? And so this is `gcc` and `clang` bugs, because they accept such code with `pedantic`?

Comment: The last variant is OK because then `Boo::f()` is in `namespace foo`, so its argument types will be looked for in the same namespace.  As for GCC and Clang, I don't think they'd agree it's a bug, they just happen to accept code that they don't have to accept.  You can't expect pedantic mode to be perfect--it's not.

Comment: For a name used in the definition of a function where the function is a member of user-declared namespace the block in which the name is used is searched before the use of the name, then the enclosing block is searched before the start of that block http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup

Comment: According to this rules should be applied the same for `using foo::Boo; void Boo::f` and `void foo::Boo::f`, in both cases `f` inside `Boo` inside `foo`, and so lookup should be works in the same way, why do you think that should be different lookup methods used?